# recursive ordered node coloring

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, pseudocode

I want to color all nodes of a given graph according to a given node ordering: the order is set through the `Iterator<Node> nodeIterator` parameter which contains all the nodes to process in the right order.

A node is colored if its neighbor is not and if a certain condition between the two considered nodes is met. A node is colored if it is an element of the parameter `vector`. A node is colored with its pre-defined color.

here's my code:

```
  #Recursive method colorNodes
    colorNodes(Graph graph,Iterator<Node> nodeIterator, Vector vector)
        if (vector.size() == graph.size())
            return true;
        node = nodeIterator.next();
        nodeNeighbors = node.getNeighbors();
        while(nodeNeighbors.hasnext()) {
            neighbor = nodeNeighbors.next();
            if (!nodeIsColored(vector, neighbor)) {
                if(conditionBetweenNodeAndNeighbor is true) {
                    vector.add(node) #color current node 
                    colorNodes(graph, nodeIterator,vector)#call recursively the method
                }
            }  
            else if (!nodeNeighbors.hasNext()) {
                    #potential last node or isolated node (having one neighbor only)
                  if(conditionBetweenNodeAndNeighbor is true) {
                    vector.add(node) #color last node anyway 
                    colorNodes(graph, nodeIterator,vector)#call recursively the method
                    }
                   }
            else {
                    continue;
                }
          return false;
        }
```

Could anyone clarify how to approach this problem and if my approach is correct (especially the cases differentiation)?

Comment: 1. Does `node.getNeighbors()` of node 3 (for example) also returns node 2 ? 2. Does coloring depend on previous nodes or only on next nodes ?

Comment: yes of course `node.getNeighbors()` of node 3 will return node 2. coloring will depend on the condition `!nodeIsColored(vector, neighbor)`. if a neighbor is colored then it is not good to check the `conditionBetweenNodeAndNeighbor `. to answer your question:  coloring then could depend on "previous" "neighbor" nodes if they are not colored.

Comment: So how do you define a leaf ? It should have one neighbor but this can also apply to the root.

Comment: this a graph not a tree, one last node to color could be unconnected to other nodes, or having 3 neighbors (2 of them already colored) .... i don't understand your question here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure I fully understood the requirement. Please check this pseudo code:

```
    //Recursive method colorNodes
    colorNodes(Graph graph,Iterator<Node> nodeIterator, Vector vector){
        
        if (vector.size() == graph.size())   return true;
        node = nodeIterator.next();       
        neighbors = node.getNeighbors()
        
        //check if leaf or isolted or all neigbors colored 
        if( (! nodeIterator.hasNext())  or  (neighbor.length == 0)   or (allNodesAreColored(neighbors))  ) { 
            //color leaf 
            if(conditionBetweenNodeAndNeighbor is true) {
                vector.add(node) 
                node.setColor(color)
                // no need for recursive call for a leaf 
            }
            return;
        }
        
        for(neighbor : neighbors ){

            if ((!nodeIsColored(vector, neighbor) and
                    (conditionBetweenNodeAndNeighbor is true) ){
                    vector.add(node) 
                    node.setColor(color)
                    colorNodes(graph, nodeIterator,vector)
                    //break if you don't want to check rest of the neighbors 
             }
         }                      
     }
```

Comment: ok thanks. First why do you think my code proposition is wrong ?

Comment: I didn't say it was wrong. I find it a little bit hard (for me) to follow. I have 3 comments about it: 1. the recursive call at a leaf is not needed 2. `else continue` is also not needed (if `return false` is needed : simply put it after the end of the `while` loop) 3. `for` loop is more concise and clearer in this case

Comment: `if(! nodeNeighbors.hasNext()) { //leaf ...`  here `nodeNeighbors` is not defined

Comment: also leaf is an isolated node or maybe the last node to color ? is that right ?

Comment: Sorry for the typo. It should be `nodeIterator`. Define "isolated node"

Comment: indeed your code is more "recursion practices friendly"

Comment: by isolated node i mean: last node to color OR a node that is unconnected to other nodes OR that has all of its neighbors already colored.

Comment: i think in your case, isolated node is the last node to color

Comment: also for the `for(neighbor : node.getNeighbors()){` loop it should break if the node is colored and not look for other potential uncolored neighbors. otherwise you would color the same color many times. am i right ?
`

Comment: It depends on your need. Is it wrong to have other neighbors colored ?

Comment: See my edit to meet _by isolated node i mean: last node to color OR a node that is unconnected to other nodes OR that has all of its neighbors already colored_

Comment: You also (same as me) are coloring the current node (not the neighbors) based on the condition between the current node and the neighbors: which is what i want. actually, i understand that you implement the same logic of my code but with a different more adequate recursive structure, is that correct ?

Comment: i rather want to stop the loop when a node is colored, and not check any further neighbor (as you do the `break` in the comment in your code), otherwise it may color the same node many times is that correct.

Comment: also in your first if statement: `or  (neighbor.length == 0)   or (allNodesAreColored(neighbors)) ` those condition could block the processing of remaining nodes in the vector, no ?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by the last comment. I don't see that the nodes in the vector are processed at all. In simple words it means: if conditions are met, do not process neighbors

Comment: 1. _"you implement the same logic of my code"_ yes, as far as I can tell. I mainly change the sequence to make it easier to follow (readable) and more concise.  2. _"otherwise it may color the same node many times"_ yes, unless you apply different logic or different color to different neighbors.

Comment: At this point I think it would be more beneficial to write the actual code, test it and debug it.

Comment: sry again, when we put `//break if you don't want to check rest of the neighbors ` isn't the recursive call dealing with that already ? what's the point of break after the recursive call `colorNodes` ?

Comment: You wrote _"otherwise it may color the same node many times"_

Comment: At this point I think it would be more beneficial to write the actual code, test it and debug it.

Comment: then i asked `is that correct?` i was not sure, anyways, i actually debug it and it is OK, i just wanted to add that `break` there is of no use.

Answer (score 1):

I merely give an answer as the recursion is a bit awkward. I would expect the following - not regarding the logic.

```
// Recursive method colorNodes
void colorNodes(Graph graph, Iterator<Node> nodeIterator, List<Node> vector)
    //if (vector.size() == graph.size())
    //    return true;
    if (!nodeIterator.hasNext()) {
        return;
    }
    Node node = nodeIterator.next();
    if (nodeIsColored(vector, node)) {
        return;
    }               
    // Here the node is processed before the children, to stop recursion.
    ​vector.add(node);
    for (Node neighbor: node.getNeighbors()) {
        //if (!nodeIsColored(vector, neighbor)) {               
            colorNodes(graph, nodeIterator,vector);
        //}  
    }
    // Here the node could be processed after the children.
}
```

`Vector<>` is the old class, and still lives under that name in for instance C++.

Comment: thanks this is also a good recursive method structure!

Comment: for your comment about the vector class, it is actually a structure that is growing in a previous code, that's why i use vector and not just a fixed list of elements.

Comment: `List` has the same functionality, growing, add&remove. `Vector` now is very rarely used, it is slower because of concurrency safeness; something that can be solved differerently (see class Collections too).

Comment: To add to waht @JoopEggen suggested: to avoid duplicates you can use a [Set](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html)

Comment: c0der && JoopEggen one last quick question, if i had to add a color backtracking mechanism (to uncolor a node and try another recursive call to see if the condition check then passes) where would the call be located within the code you provided ?

Comment: That is really hard for me, because I have not all sources. Then a boolean return type, whether recursion did not fail might be needed. But really there I cannot help you. Play it on paper.